# Firebase Cloud Messaging Unauthorized Error 401 on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have almost succeeded in setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging. I am stuck on the last step i.e. sending the cloud message to the device.
 I am using a google chrome extension 'Postman' to post the message.

[image: Image Description]

I receive Unauthorized error 401 whenever I send the message. Can anyone hint me where I maybe going wrong ?

Comment: Are you using the Server Key or FCM token from the Cloud Messaging tab in your Firebase Console?

Comment: @AL. I am using the API key in the authorization

Comment: I meant, where did you get the value from? In your Google Developer Console or Firebase Console?

Comment: @AL. I have used the server key in the firebase console

Comment: That's strange. Did you set any Key restrictions via the Google Developer console?

Comment: I am able to send messages through this [link](https://ninjakoders.github.io/sample/gcm-push-demo/), but not with postman or curl

Comment: Can you try changing the body to *raw* then send a simple payload like `{
    "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
    "data": {
      "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
     }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue. Follow the steps below:

1. Go to Firebase Console
2. Go to your Project
3. Go to Settings
4. Select Cloud Messaging Tab
5. Copy the Server Key (usually starts with AAA****) and apply in your request.

Hope this helps! :)